# RandomVariate does not evaluate a Hyperbolic Distribution

Tags: random, distributions, simulation

Any Idea why I can't get a result from this expression:

```
In[170]:= RandomVariate[HyperbolicDistribution[59.428`, 18.441`, 3.428`*^-9, -0.00065`]]

Out[170]= RandomVariate[HyperbolicDistribution[59.428, 18.441, 3.428*10^-9, -0.00065]]
```

I have found this distribution in modelling the daily balance of a bank in order to calculate liquidity risk.

Comment: Apparently `3.428 10^-9` is too small. `3.428 10^-7` works OK, though

Comment: It doesn't look like the impact of the third parameter is really large at the given value. The plot of the PDF remains visually unchanged if you increase it by a factor of 1000.

Comment: *Sjoerd* raised a good point: Increasing delta by a factor of 100 still gives results that match to 7+ decimal places. Doing so allows use of `RandomVariate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a glitch, however you can invert the CDF to get the desired result (not as fast, of course):

```
InverseCDF[HyperbolicDistribution[1, 59.428`, 18.441`, 3.428`*^-9, -0.00065`], 
            RandomReal[1, 10]]

(* {0.000448962, 0.0144836, 0.0481936, -0.0169342, 0.0445246, -0.0151702, 0.00316436, 0.00877931, 0.085059, 0.00880039} *)
```

Comment: Many thanks mate!